# Why do I get 404 when using multiple sub-routers?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I have been exploring express.js 4.13+. Looks quite nice. However, when using multiple sub-routers, I can only reach endpoints declared at the first one. The remaining routes keeps throwing 404. Requests do not seem to get propagated down the route stack.

app.js

```
...
app.use(require('./controllers'));
app.use(require('./middlewares/404'));
...
```

controllers/index.js

```
module.exports = router = new Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});

router.use('/empty', require('./empty')); // works
router.use('/member', require('./user')); // throws 404 works only if above mount is removed.
```

controllers/empty.js

```
var Router = require('express').Router; 
module.exports = router = new Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('empty');
});
```

Navigating to `/` and `/empty` works as expected however all routes under `/member` fails with 404. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the use of `module.exports = router = new Router();` pattern. My understanding is that the previous statement exports `router` as a global variable that is used in various places in the code. Changing this statement to `var router = module.exports = new Router();` did the trick.